# Nested for...each loops with If statements

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am new to vb.script so this may just be a formatting question that I cannot find the answer.
The problem is validating data in cells that are on different sheets in the same workbook.

Looping through worksheets and then looping through the cell range:

```
Private Sub Validate(ByRef objWorkbook As Workbook)

Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "^\-{0,1}\d+(.\d+){0,1}$"
Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim strInput As String
Dim strOutput As String
Dim Myrange As Range
Dim regExCount As Object
Set regExCount = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
On Error Resume Next

For Each objWorksheet In objWorkbook.Worksheets
    If (UCase(objWorksheet.Name) = "Foo") Then
        objWorksheet.Select
        Range("Q2").Select

    ElseIf (UCase(objWorksheet.Name) = "Bar") Or (UCase(objWorksheet.Name) = "Poo") Then
        objWorksheet.Select
        Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("D51:AA76")

        For Each cell In Myrange.Cells
            If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = cell.Value
            strReplace = ""

            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With

            Set regExCount = regEx.Execute(strInput)
            If regExCount.Count = 0 Then
                strOutput = strOutput + "Illegal character at " + cell.AddressLocal + "\r\n"
            End If
        Next cell
    End If

Next
MsgBox (strOutput)

End Sub
```

When I compile I get an error of a Next without a For loop at the Next Cell.  Removing that line and I get an error for Block If without an End Ff highlighting the End Sub.  Adding an End If before the End sub and I get a Next without a For error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it this block missing and end if?

```
        If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = cell.Value
            strReplace = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
If strPattern <> "" Then
```

is not closed between

```
    End If ' regExCount.Count
Next cell ' In Myrange.Cells
```